# QR Code Wi-Fi Static IP

Tags: qr-code, android-wifi, static-ip-address

I've found a way to connect Wi-Fi via barcode. For example I can generate a barcode with the content below:

```
WIFI:T:WPA;S:mynetwork;P:mypass;;
```

Then I'm able to connect to it.

But is it possible to also set other Wi-Fi settings like **static IP** or **DNS Server**?